# How to get the selected BezierPath on MouseDown or MouseDragged or MouseUp?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsevent, nsbezierpath

I am drawing multiple NSBezierpaths, then I am trying to erase them so on MouseDown event How can I identify which bezierpath was hit?
My bezierpath is custom subclass of NSObject.

Answer (score 0):

Well, get the mouse click point from the `NSEvent` in your `mouseDown:` method with `-locationInWindow`, convert the click point from window coordinates to your view's coordinates with `-convertPoint:fromView:`, loop through the `NSBezierPath` objects that you're drawing, from top to bottom, and call `-containsPoint:` to test for a hit on each path.  That works well if your bezier paths are closed, filled paths.  If they are unclosed or stroked paths, you will need to drop down a level and use `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()`, and perhaps also `CGPathCreateCopyByDashingPath()`, to get the fill-style bezier path that describes the outline of the area that is filled when your original path is stroked (see [How to get the path Quartz is using to stroke a NSBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11401681/how-to-get-the-path-quartz-is-using-to-stroke-a-nsbezierpath)).

However, I'm not sure what you mean by "My bezierpath is custom subclass of NSObject"; if you are doing additional complicated things beyond just using `NSBezierPath`, then you will need to describe what you're doing (and why), and post code for it.

Comment: If there are 10,000 bezierpaths,I need to loop through all of them and it will be very slow.What I am currently doing is  creating a hitPoint like  'NSPoint hitPt = [self convertPoint:[inEvent locationInWindow] fromView:self];' and then creating a Rect from it and create another Rect from NSBezierpath bounds ,and I am checking if these two Rect intersect each other using (NSIntersectsRect(hitPointRect,bezierPathRect) ,If they do I am working only with that bezierPath.But still i have to loop through all bezierpaths.So I want to identify the bezierPath on mouseDown.

Comment: Your strategy sounds fine.  You might cache the bounds of all your bezier paths, so that you're looping through an array of cached `NSRect`s instead of through the paths themselves.  Looping through 10,000 `NSRect`s to do inside/outside checks should take very little time, and then if the number of potential "hits" is fairly small, doing the actual hit-test on each candidate bezier path shouldn't be a problem.  If you're having to use `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()`, you might need to cache those converted paths, too, for speed, but you might not.

Comment: Oh, and you probably want to use `NSPointInRect()` to do the inside/outside checks, rather than `NSIntersectsRect()`, unless I'm missing something.  The hit point is a point, there's no reason to convert it to a rect.  `NSPointInRect()` should be faster than `NSIntersectsRect()`.  If view flipping gets in your way, `NSMouseInRect()` is specifically designed for hit-testing in views that can be flipped.

Comment: If this sort of simple hit-testing is too slow even with caching of bounds rects and converted paths, then you will need to get into some kind of complicated spatial subdivision algorithm like keeping a [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree) with linked lists of the objects contained within each quad.  That gets very complicated very fast, though, and Cocoa will provide little help for you in doing it.  I would be very surprised if it was necessary with only 10,000 paths.  Computers are fast.  :->